# Trigger on insert; instead of A do B

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, database-trigger

I have two tables: `warehouse` and `inventory`:

```
CREATE TABLE warehouse (
    bin VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    qty INT
    PRIMARY KEY(bin)
);

CREATE TABLE inventory (
    item INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(item)
);
```

I want to set a trigger such that any insertion on `inventory`, if that insertion does not have a unique name, add that to `warehouse` too, otherwise increase `warehouse.qty` appropriately.

If I were to insert a row into `inventory`:

```
INSERT INTO inventory 
VALUES('', 'hammer");

 inventory         warehouse
----------------------------
item | name        bin | qty
----------------------------
 1    hammer        1     1
```

A row in `inventory` has been added, but also a row in `warehouse`. Then another unique row is added:

```
INSERT INTO inventory 
VALUES('', 'pliers");

 inventory         warehouse
----------------------------
item | name        bin | qty
----------------------------
 1    hammer        1     1
 2    pliers        2     1
```

Finally a second hammer is added.

```
INSERT INTO inventory 
VALUES('', 'hammer");

 inventory         warehouse
----------------------------
item | name        bin | qty
----------------------------
 1    hammer        1     2
 2    pliers        2     1
```

Note when the second 'hammer' insertion happened, a new row was not added to `inventory`, instead the related row in `warehouse` had its `qty` incremented.

How do I create this trigger in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [14.1.18 CREATE TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)
>
> ...
>
> - Some attributes do not apply to all data types. AUTO_INCREMENT applies only to integer and floating-point types. DEFAULT does not apply to the BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY, and JSON types.
>
> ...

```sql
CREATE TABLE warehouse (
    bin VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- <- It's not possible
    qty INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(bin)
);
```

You may have some options, with some considerations:

- If `item` column must strictly follow the sequence (AUTO_INCREMENT), you can encapsulate in a stored procedure `INSERT` logic:

Example [Rextester](http://rextester.com/YTW35355):

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_inventory`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `warehouse`, `inventory`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `warehouse` (
    ->     `bin` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    ->     `qty` INT DEFAULT 1,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(`bin`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
    ->     `item` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     `name` VARCHAR(10),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(`item`),
    ->     UNIQUE KEY(`name`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_ai_inventory` AFTER INSERT ON `inventory`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    ->     INSERT INTO `warehouse` (`bin`)
    ->     VALUES (NEW.`item`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_inventory`(`_name` VARCHAR(10))
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE `_item` INT DEFAULT (SELECT `item`
    ->                                  FROM `inventory`
    ->                                  WHERE `name` = `_name`);
    ->     IF `_item` IS NULL THEN
    ->         INSERT INTO `inventory` (`name`)
    ->         VALUES (`_name`);
    ->     ELSE
    ->         UPDATE `warehouse`
    ->         SET `qty` = `qty` + 1
    ->         WHERE `bin` = `_item`;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `insert_inventory`('hammer');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    1 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_inventory`('hammer');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    2 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_inventory`('pliers');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
|    2 | pliers |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    2 |
| 2   |    1 |
+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

- If `item` column not must strictly follow the sequence
  (AUTO_INCREMENT), you can use [14.2.5 INSERT Syntax::IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) or [14.2.5.3 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

IGNORE (Example [Rextester](http://rextester.com/PHHIA90684)):

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `warehouse`, `inventory`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `warehouse` (
    ->     `bin` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    ->     `qty` INT DEFAULT 1,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(`bin`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
    ->     `item` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     `name` VARCHAR(10),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(`item`),
    ->     UNIQUE KEY(`name`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bi_inventory` BEFORE INSERT ON `inventory`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE `_item` INT DEFAULT (SELECT `item`
    ->                                  FROM `inventory`
    ->                                  WHERE `name` = NEW.`name`);
    ->     IF `_item` IS NOT NULL THEN
    ->         UPDATE `warehouse`
    ->         SET `qty` = `qty` + 1
    ->         WHERE `bin` = `_item`;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_ai_inventory` AFTER INSERT ON `inventory`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    ->     INSERT INTO `warehouse` (`bin`)
    ->     VALUES (NEW.`item`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE `inventory` (`name`)
    -> VALUES ('hammer');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    1 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE `inventory` (`name`)
    -> VALUES ('hammer');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    2 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE `inventory` (`name`)
    -> VALUES ('pliers');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
|    3 | pliers |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    2 |
| 3   |    1 |
+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (Example [Rextester](http://rextester.com/UAVPGR88064)):

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `warehouse`, `inventory`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `warehouse` (
    ->     `bin` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    ->     `qty` INT DEFAULT 1,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(`bin`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
    ->     `item` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     `name` VARCHAR(10),
    ->     `count` INT DEFAULT 1,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY(`item`),
    ->     UNIQUE KEY(`name`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_ai_inventory` AFTER INSERT ON `inventory`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    ->     INSERT INTO `warehouse` (`bin`)
    ->     VALUES (NEW.`item`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_au_inventory` AFTER UPDATE ON `inventory`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    ->     UPDATE `warehouse`
    ->     SET `qty` = `qty` + 1
    ->     WHERE `bin` = OLD.`item`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `inventory` (`name`)
    -> VALUES ('hammer')
    ->     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    1 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `inventory` (`name`)
    -> VALUES ('hammer')
    ->     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    2 |
+-----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `inventory` (`name`)
    -> VALUES ('pliers')
    ->     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count` = `count` + 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `item`, `name`
    -> FROM `inventory`;
+------+--------+
| item | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | hammer |
|    3 | pliers |
+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `bin`, `qty`
    -> FROM `warehouse`;
+-----+------+
| bin | qty  |
+-----+------+
| 1   |    2 |
| 3   |    1 |
+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```